# Flutter driver not able to enter 2 different sub texts in the same text field which is rich text formatted like hh:mm

Tags: flutter, appium, flutter-web, flutterdriver

I am using flutter driver to automate the mobile app,

And I am blocked with this case,

I am trying to entering into a rich text field that is formatted. like hh : mm as and when I type hours the app automatically puts the colon and moves to the next part of the mm in the text field. Via automation it is always replacing the hh and not moving the control to mm. Could you please help me here how this can be achieved?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.